# Simultaneous vanishing $\mathbb{Q}$-linear relations between $N$-th roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $N$-th root of unity and $\Gamma \subset (\mathbb{Z}/N)^\times$ a subgroup. Let $|\Gamma|$ be the cardinality of $\Gamma$ and consider the linear map $M_\Gamma\colon \mathbb{Q}^{N-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^{(N-1)\cdot |\Gamma|}$ given by the matrix
\begin{align*}
 M_\Gamma = (\zeta^{nir}-\zeta^{ni})_{i=1,...,N-1 \atop (n,r)\in \{1,...,N-1\}\times \Gamma}.
\end{align*}
**My question(s):** What is the kernel of $M_\Gamma$? Is there any known result about this that I am missing?

**Remark:** There is Theorem 2.2 in the paper of Lam and Leung *“On vanishing sums of roots of unity”*, which gives a description of all $\mathbb{Z}$-linear relations among $N$-th roots of unity. However, I'm interested in those $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations given by the set of equations encoded in $M_\Gamma$ for a subgroup $\Gamma\subset (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times$.